# How to install Visual C++ runtime 14 on Wine?

Tags: dependencies, wine

I am trying to install SketchUp on Wine. One of the prerequisites is `Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64)`.

When I try to run the installer, it fails with `0x8007065b - Function failed`. The installer calls itself `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.36.32532` and was either downloaded or extracted by the SketchUp installer.

How can I get the C++ 14 runtime to install on Wine?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use [Winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks):

```
winetricks vcrun2015
```